# NextAuth React Server Components Dynamic server usage Error

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next-auth, react-server-components

Been trying to use react server components, however, I'm stuck at retrieving session data from next auth. The recommended way to do this is `getServerSession` which throws an error:

```
Error: Dynamic server usage: force-dynamic
```

As per docs, I've set dynamic option to `force-dynamic`, however, the error persists regardless of the value. Interestingly enough, the page loads fine when refreshed on the "server component" route, however, when navigating to it from a different page, it throws an error

```js
import {authOptions} from 'path/to/[...nextauth]'
export const dynamic = 'force-dynamic'
export default async function Page() {
  const session = await getServerSession(authOptions);
  return null;
```

UPDATE:

If `dynamic` is left with default value, the error message changes to:

```
Error: Dynamic server usage: headers

  14 | export default async function Page(...props: any) {
> 15 | const session = await getServerSession(authOptions);
     |                                       ^
  16 | return null;
```

the behaviour stays the same, meaning it loads fine when on the rsc route, but throws error when navigating to it

Comment: In the new /app directory, components are server components by default unless you specify "use client"; at the top of the file / at the top of the function. Why is there a need to use this 'force-dynamic'-option? I'm using server components and I've not heard about that option before, but after reading the documentation for it (https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/route-segment-config#dynamic), I think there are other ways to achieve what you want.

Comment: @kzi yeah that's just something that I've tried before posting here. I've updated the main post to include an error message when dynamic is left with default value e.g., auto

Comment: For somebody here https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/50634 it worked to use `export const dynamic = "force-static";` for static pages. Maybe this is worth a try.

Comment: First you asked why I used it then you suggest I use it to fix the issue. I don't get you....

Comment: Please look at the statement again, it's slightly different than the one, you use. But I don't know if that will help you. The cause of the error may be somewhere in the code that you didn't post. Your usage of getServerSession looks correct as far as I can say. Edit: I saw, you could solve your issue, glad to know.

Comment: Yeah you're right, didn't notice it was different. My bad, thanks for the help 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, as it turns out, the issue was 'caused by another server component which sets up my next-intl and uses the `generateStaticParams` function. Once I set it to undefined it worked fine.

```js
function getStaticParams(){...}

export const generateStaticParams = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? getStaticParams : undefined
```